# infinite loop in shell sort implementation in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, java, algorithm, sorting

I'm currently reading the fourth edition of `Algorithms, 4th Edition by Robert Sedgewick` where the author has an implementation of shell sort. I'm trying to understand why this implementation is not working in JavaScript. Although I'm able to `console.log` the sorted array, it seems the program never stops running and it becomes an infinite loop.

```
 public class Shell
  {
     public static void sort(Comparable[] a)
     {  // Sort a[] into increasing order.
        int N = a.length;
        int h = 1;
        while (h < N/3) h = 3*h + 1; // 1, 4, 13, 40, 121, 364, 1093, ...
        while (h >= 1)
        {  // h-sort the array.
           for (int i = h; i < N; i++)
           {  // Insert a[i] among a[i-h], a[i-2*h], a[i-3*h]... .
              for (int j = i; j >= h && less(a[j], a[j-h]); j -= h)
                 exch(a, j, j-h);
           }
           h = h/3; }
         }
     // See page 245 for less(), exch(), isSorted(), and main().
}
```

The above is the implementation in Java. Notice how the first loop `while (h < N/3) h = 3*h + 1;` doesn't have `{}` opening or closing braces, does it mean it goes till the end?

Here is my implementation in JavaScript:

```
function shellSort(a) {
  let N = a.length;
  let h = 1;

  while (h < N/3) {
    h = 3 * h + 1

    while (h >= 1) 
    {
      for (let i = h; i < N; i++) 
      {
        for (let j = i; j >= h && a[j] < a[j - h]; j -= h){
        let temp = a[j - h]
          a[j - h] = a[j]
          a[j] = temp
        }
      }
      console.log(a)
      h = h/3
    }
  }
}

console.log(shellSort([7,11,3,6,2,5,9,8,1,10]))
```

When I log the output I get the sorted array but I don't know where the infinite loop comes from. When you run the code this is whats output to terminal:

```
  7, 8, 9, 10, 11
]
[
  1, 2, 3,  5,  6,
  7, 8, 9, 10, 11
]
[
  1, 2, 3,  5,  6,
  7, 8, 9, 10, 11
]
[
  1, 2, 3,  5,  6,
  7, 8, 9, 10, 11
]
```

What is the problem? I tried adding a `Math.floor` to  `h/3` but without luck.
What did I get wrong?

Comment: Regarding the first loop, no it does not mean what you think. If you're not sure you can [test it by itself to see what it does](http://jdoodle.com/a/21bE). Notice in this example "hello" is printed only once.

Comment: weird how it works in `Java`, so this wouldn't work for javascript I tried `while(){} while{`

Comment: but that didn't work either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java and integer divided by an integer is still an integer:

```java
int x = 5;
int y = x / 3;
// prints "1"
System.out.println(y);
```

In Javascript however, there are no integers, everything is a Number. Then,

```
let x = 5;
let y = x / 3;
// prints "1.6666666666666"
console.log(y);
```

Your algorithm requires `h` to be an integer, otherwise it's hard to use it as an array index. You have to cast it to an integer explicitly. Fixed-up Javascript implementation:

```
function shellSort(a) {
  let N = a.length;
  let h = 1;

  while (h < N / 3) {
    h = 3 * h + 1;
  }


  while (h >= 1) {
    for (let i = h; i < N; i++) {
      for (let j = i; j >= h && a[j] < a[j - h]; j -= h) {
        let temp = a[j - h]
        a[j - h] = a[j]
        a[j] = temp
      }
    }
    // parseInt here is key
    h = parseInt(h / 3)
  }

}
console.log(shellSort([7, 11, 3, 6, 2, 5, 9, 8, 1, 10]))
```